How come this value is both 0 and not 0 at the same time?
I'm trying to display a cooldown timer in Godot. In my previous project the same exact code works perfectly. I imported the same exact scene into my new project and the imported scene works.
In this new project I copied and pasted this function into a new scene. The code doesn't work because remaining cooldown is always 0 and always not 0 at the same time.
func updateLabel(label: Label, cooldown: float, current_time: float, last_time: float) -> void:
    var elapsed_time: float = current_time - last_time
    var remaining_cooldown: float = max(0.0, cooldown - elapsed_time)
    print("remaining_cooldown:", remaining_cooldown)
    if remaining_cooldown!= 0:
        label.text = str(remaining_cooldown)
    else:
        label.text = ""


Perhaps it's 0.000000000000000023751.  Floats are binary numbers not decimal and their math is often off from what you'd expect.  You normally should say  x < some_tiny_value not x == 0.0  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Godot has the global function is_equal_approx().
